# coin flip simulate in python

Tags: python, simulate, coin-flipping

I want to simulate flipping a fair coin 500 times. Then I have to create a graph to show the running proportion of heads when flipping a coin with flip number on the x-axis and proportion heads on the y-axis. I wrote the Python code and I got the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "E:\ProgramsPython\My\bayes\Coin Flip.py", line 22, in <module>
ylist = [coinFlip(x) for x in xlist]
File "E:\ProgramsPython\My\bayes\Coin Flip.py", line 16, in coinFlip
return heads / x
ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero
```

What did I do wrong?

```
# -*- coding: cp1251 -*-
import random
import pylab
from matplotlib import mlab
def coinFlip(size):
    heads = 0
    tails = 0

    for x in xrange(size):
        flip = random.randint(0,1)
        if flip == 1: heads += 1
        else: tails += 1



    return heads / x

xmin = 1
xmax = 500
dx = 1
xlist = mlab.frange (xmin, xmax, dx)
ylist = [coinFlip(x) for x in xlist]
pylab.plot(xlist, ylist)
pylab.show()
```

Comment: In addition to all the feedback about dividing by zero, I'm not sure you're doing what you were asked to do.  When you get this running, it's going to plot 500 independent sampling results based on different sample sizes. The running proportion should plot how the proportion changes with each additional coin flip in a single experiment of 500 flips.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
In [53]: [x for x in xrange(1)]
Out[53]: [0]
```

`x` can equal zero. When that happens, (in particular, when `coinFlip(1)` is called),

```
heads / x
```

raises a ZeroDivisionError.

---

By the way, since you are using `matplotlib`, you must have `NumPy` installed. Therefore, you could use express `coinFlip` like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def coinFlip(size):
    flips = np.random.randint(0, 2, size=size)
    return flips.mean()
coinFlip = np.frompyfunc(coinFlip, 1, 1)

xmin, xmax, dx = 1, 500, 1
x = np.arange(xmin, xmax, dx)
y = coinFlip(x)
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

[image]

---

Or (using @pjs's comment), to see how the proportion of heads changes during a single run of 500 coin flips:

```
def coinFlip(size):
    xmin, xmax, dx = 1, size, 1
    x = np.arange(xmin, xmax, dx)
    flips = np.random.randint(0, 2, size=size)
    return x, [flips[:i].mean() for i in x]

x, y = coinFlip(500)
plt.plot(x, y)
```

[image]

---

To plot the x-axis on a log scale:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x, y)
ax.set_xscale('log')
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it's what I really want. And one more question, how can I plot x-axis on a logarithmic scale so then I can see the details of the first few flips and also the long-run trend after many flips?

Answer (score 3):

Well, the error says you are dividing by zero. So there is one line where you divide, it's probably there.

Try changing your return to this (makes more sense anyway in my opinion):

```
return heads / size
```

Comment: If you do this, don't forget to ensure `size` isn't 0.

Comment: Based on the rest of OP's code, size won't be 0 (it will be something between 1 and 500). But it probably is good practice to perform some kind of check

Answer (score 2):

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

flips = np.random.binomial(1, 0.5, 500) # flip 1 coin with 0.5 prob of heads 500 times
heads_so_far = flips.cumsum() * 1.0 #lets use float to avoid truncations later
heads_to_count = [heads_so_far[i-1]/i for i in range(1,len(flips)+1)]
x = range(1,len(flips)+1)
plt.plot(x,heads_to_count)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to divide `heads` by `size`

To avoid truncating, it should probably be

```
     return heads / float(size)
```

Answer (score 0):

When the line
return heads / x 
is run the last time, then x is 0 thus creating the division by zero error.